# Enable an User Authentication in EmbeddedD Derby

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have a program that has a menu with two options
 first,to create a new database 
 second,open existing database

my database creation part code is as follows

```
public EmbeddedDerby(String dbName, String userName, String pass) throws SQLException {
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + "dist/" + dbName + ""
                + ";create=true;user=" + userName + " " + ";password=" + pass + "");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
        rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "DBNAME", null);
        String sqlTabel = "CREATE TABLE APP.DBNAME"
                + "(NAME VARCHAR(255) not null primary key,"
                + "TEL   VARCHAR(10))";
        st.execute(sqlTabel);
        }
```

my database opening part is as follows

```
 public void openDataBase(String dbName, String userName, String pass) throws SQLException {
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + "dist/" + dbName + ""
                + ";user=" + userName + ";password=" + pass + "");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        }
```

I have no issue with creating a new database, but when I want to open existing database, it does not check whether I enter a right username and password or not. Moreover, it accepts any username and password as long as name of a database exists. I thought getConnection method will check correctness of username and password, yet it seems I am totally wrong.
Could anyone tell me what is wrong and how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System Level` set properties using java to enable authenticatication.

```
Properties p=System.getProperties();
p.put("derby.connection.requireAuthentication", "true");
```

`Database Level` set properties to enable authentication.

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(
    'derby.connection.requireAuthentication',
    'true')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevcsecure42374.html):

> When user authentication is enabled (which it is not by default), the user requesting a connection must provide a valid name and password, which Derby verifies against the repository of users defined for the system.

Have you enabled user authentication? Again, from the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevcsecure36127.html):

> To enable user authentication, set the `derby.connection.requireAuthentication` property to `true`. Otherwise, Derby does not require a user name and password. You can set this property as a system-wide property or as a database-wide property.
>
> For a multi-user product, you would typically set it for the system in the derby.properties file for your server, since it is in a trusted environment.

Comment: thank you for your fast response, yet how I can do apply this idea in java code?

Comment: @KickButtowski Authentication should be forced by database

Comment: could you be more clear about what you said?
I have tried to find some piece of code online, yet I have not been able to find a good answer.
Could you tell me how I either force or enable authentication for derby?

 Properties d = new Properties();
        d.setProperty("derby.connection.requireAuthentication", "true");

but it does not work or make sense ?

Comment: The Derby doc [Enabling user authentication](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevcsecure36127.html) tells you to set a property in the `derby.properties` file for your server. The first hit on a google for "derby.properties file" found the doc [Changing the system-wide properties by using the derby.properties file](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/tuning/ctunsetprop13074.html). That doc clearly states that **you must create, write, and edit this file yourself**. And that doc tells you where to do so.

Comment: as you see, I use embedded derby, so how I can apply this idea for embedded derby with java code?

Comment: plz i need to know how I can set this properties for authentication by java code in my program.